Changed url key of product does not change in product grid in admin?
Magento 2.4.6-p4
I am chaning the url key by using
$product->setUrlKey('newkey1234');
$product->save();

Now, when I view this product in admin, it still shows the old url key. Loading the product and printing the url key shows the new key:
var_dump($product->getUrlKey());

So, how can I also make it change in admin?
Thanks!

You can defne the storeID as well. Please do as given below :
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block\Quote;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Items extends Template {

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productrepo,
    ProductFactory $product,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->productrepo = $productrepo;
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function ProductUrl($sku)
{
    $product = $this->productrepo->get($sku);
    $product->setStoreId(0);//setting the value on all store view
    $product->setUrlKey('add your url key'); // Replace with your desired URL key
    $this->productrepo->save($product);
}
}


First please run bin/magento s:up;bin/magento index:reindex and then check
if doesn't work still run this command and let me know the result, might be attribute scope issue.
select a.*
from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` a
join `eav_attribute` b
    on b.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
where b.attribute_code = 'url_key'
and a.entity_id = 12673;

change entity_id with your product id

Just a wild guess, but maybe you're missing setUrlPath()?
$product->setUrlPath('newkey1234');
$product->setUrlKey('newkey1234');
$product->save();

